# How to distinguish between 'TABLE_CAT' and 'TABLE_CATALOG' when writing JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

When writing JDBC code to adapt DBvaver software, I don't know who to pass the database name to.

For example, in the `getTables()` function, the returned result set has the following parameters:

```
ResultSet getTables(String catalog,
                  String schemaPattern,
                  String tableNamePattern,
                  String[] types)
                    throws SQLException
Retrieves a description of the tables available in the given catalog. Only table descriptions matching the catalog, schema, table name and type criteria are returned. They are ordered by TABLE_TYPE, TABLE_CAT, TABLE_SCHEM and TABLE_NAME.
Each table description has the following columns:

TABLE_CAT String => table catalog (may be null)
TABLE_SCHEM String => table schema (may be null)
TABLE_NAME String => table name
TABLE_TYPE String => table type. Typical types are "TABLE", "VIEW", "SYSTEM TABLE", "GLOBAL TEMPORARY", "LOCAL TEMPORARY", "ALIAS", "SYNONYM".
REMARKS String => explanatory comment on the table
TYPE_CAT String => the types catalog (may be null)
TYPE_SCHEM String => the types schema (may be null)
TYPE_NAME String => type name (may be null)
SELF_REFERENCING_COL_NAME String => name of the designated "identifier" column of a typed table (may be null)
REF_GENERATION String => specifies how values in SELF_REFERENCING_COL_NAME are created. Values are "SYSTEM", "USER", "DERIVED". (may be null)
Note: Some databases may not return information for all tables.
```

But in the `getSchemas()` function, the returned result set has the following parameters:

```
ResultSet getSchemas()
                     throws SQLException
Retrieves the schema names available in this database. The results are ordered by TABLE_CATALOG and TABLE_SCHEM.
The schema columns are:

TABLE_SCHEM String => schema name
TABLE_CATALOG String => catalog name (may be null)
```

I would like to know the difference between `TABLE_CAT` in `getTables()` and `TABLE_CATALOG` in `getSchemas()`, and what values should be given to them. The database name or the table name.

Answer (score 0):

Both `TABLE_CAT` and `TABLE_CATALOG` refer to the same concept, the *catalog*. The inconsistency in naming is simply - as far as I know - derived from how those columns are (also) named in the ODBC specification and SQL standard Schemata book. The exact meaning of *catalog* varies by database system, and some database systems don't even have one.

The catalog is not a table, it is a collection of tables (or sometimes, a collection of schemas, where schemas are a collection of tables), again meaning of these terms can differ per database system.

For MySQL Connector/J, by default, catalog represents a database, though there is a configuration option to map the database to schema instead.

See also the documentation of the configuration property `databaseTerm` in section [6.3.2 Connection](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-connp-props-connection.html) of the MySQL Connector/J 8 documentation:

> MySQL uses the term "schema" as a synonym of the term "database,"
> while Connector/J historically takes the JDBC term "catalog" as
> synonymous to "database". This property sets for Connector/J which of
> the JDBC terms "catalog" and "schema" is used in an application to
> refer to a database. The property takes one of the two values
> "CATALOG" or "SCHEMA" and uses it to determine (1) which Connection
> methods can be used to set/get the current database (e.g.
> 'setCatalog()' or 'setSchema()'?), (2) which arguments can be used
> within the various 'DatabaseMetaData' methods to filter results (e.g.
> the catalog or 'schemaPattern' argument of 'getColumns()'?), and (3)
> which fields in the result sets returned by 'DatabaseMetaData' methods
> contain the database identification information (i.e., the 'TABLE_CAT'
> or 'TABLE_SCHEM' field in the result set returned by 'getTables()'?).
>
> If "databaseTerm=CATALOG", 'schemaPattern' for searches are ignored
> and calls of schema methods (like 'setSchema()' or get 'Schema()')
> become no-ops, and vice versa.

The default is `databaseTerm=CATALOG`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your answer is very thorough. I have learned!